# Visual Studio Code blurry and with ghost text, images and colors

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron

A few updates ago my Visual Studio Code started blurring the text but this is getting more and more frequent and strong, the problem seems to be in Electron apps but it doesn't affect Discord, the other Electron app that is blurry is Insomnia, but much less blurry compared to VSCode

My computer configuration is I5 10100F, GTX 1650, 16GB, Windows 11, all drivers are up to date and Windows is up to date

```
GPU Status: 
2d_canvas: enabled
canvas_oop_rasterization: disabled_off
direct_rendering_display_compositor: disabled_off_ok
gpu_compositing: enabled
multiple_raster_threads: enabled_on
opengl: enabled_on
rasterization: enabled
raw_draw: disabled_off_ok
video_decode: enabled
video_encode: enabled
vulkan: disabled_off
webgl: enabled
webgl2: enabled
webgpu: enabled
```

[Blurred Visual Studio Code Insider Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7RuG.png)

I downloaded the Insider version of VSCode to not expose my personal, and for test if it wasn't something from the plugins and settings I installed, but the problem is the same

Comment: Got GPU status from VSCode help. Yes, disabling hardware acceleration did the trick, thanks